# Creating a Formula to make a new set of cells equal to every other row

Tags: excel-formula

I am a special education teacher creating a data sheet that can be used on an iPad for my staff to track student data.I was able to successfully create my data sheet thanks to the help of the wonderful people on this site. Now I want to be able to make sure the data graphs automatically.

My question is: I need to make a section on my sheet that copies the date placed in the data sheet for only specific rows. Since the students usually have 2 items they are working on per lesson there are 2 rows per date (one to track the data on the first item they are working on and one for the 2nd). I need to make a graph for the first item and a separate graph for the other item. There is a pattern (every other cell: First cell is =A10, the next =A12, next =A14) but when I drag the pattern it copies the pattern or uses the dates that are in the same row. Is there a formula that would help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of that could accomplish this is to use the INDEX function.

Assuming your dates are in Sheet1 column A (starting at A2 assuming you have a header row), and you want your new list of "unique dates" on Sheet2 column A (starting at A2), you would need to put the following formula in Sheet2 cell A2:

=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000,1+(2*(ROWS(A$2:A2)-1)))

Then drag that formula down. The Sheet2's A column should now show every other value from Sheet1's A column, starting at A2.

EDIT: Also, if your students ever have 3 items and you suddenly need to update your sheet to read every three dates, simply change the (2*(ROWS part of the formula to (3*(ROWS

Comment: Thank you so very much!!! It worked perfectly! I cannot thank everyone on this site enough. I am trying to create a way for may staff t be able to take student data on the iPad which will help us save so much time in graphing and other steps. All of you are helping me be able to make this happen. Thank you again.